# WCF table data to ExtJS Store

Tags: wcf, extjs, javascript

I've set up a WCF service to provide table data in JSON:

```
{
    "d":{
        "__type":"ExtJsDataResults:#MyProject.WebServices",
        "rows":[
            ["TitleA","1.98","English"],
            ["TitleB","1.98","Spanish"],
            ["TitleC","1.98","Korean"]
        ],
        "totalcount":10
    }
}
```

How to read this into an ExtJS Store? I need a JsonStore to begin with, but then an ArrayReader-type type interpret the row data. Something like this:

```
var itemStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: "../WebServices/ItemsService.svc/getData",
        method: "GET"
    }),
    root: "d.rows",
    totalProperty: "d.totalcount",
    fields: ['Book Title', 'Unit Price', 'Language'],
    reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, 
        Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name:'Book Title'},
            {name:'Unit Price'},
            {name:'Language'}
        ])
    )
});
```

Of course, this doesn't work. When bound to a DataGrid w/ a paging toolbar, it displays blank rows, but the correct number of them, and the paging toolbar values are all correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED. Changed to a regular Store and added the "root" and "totalProperty" values to the config object of the ArrayReader.

cf. this [Sencha Forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?78624-Parse-Json-whit-JsonStore)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem but got through with this solution -
http://dotnetkeeda.blogspot.in/2013/11/working-with-sencha-extjs-and-wcf.html
Nice and important tips thanks to the author.